# RichFaces Save File

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am using richfaces 3.3
I want my user to able to specify a location on the server where he can save the file.
How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use any upload component
2. use an extra component (trie-view) to represent the structure on the server
3. On submit, get the submitted file and store it on the server